# What are the limits to inheritance in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, eval

I have been trying to work out a few things about ggplot2, and how supplemntary arguments inherit from the first part `ggplot()`. Specifically, if inheritance is passed on beyond the `geom_***` part.

I have a histogram of data:

```
ggplot(data = faithful, aes(eruptions)) + geom_histogram()
```

Which produces a fine chart, though the breaks are default. It appears to me (an admitted novice), that `geom_histogram()` is inheriting the data specification from `ggplot()`. If I want to have a smarter way of setting the breaks I could use a process like so:

```
ggplot(data = faithful, aes(eruptions)) + 
geom_histogram(breaks = seq(from = min(faithful$eruptions), 
                            to = max(faithful$eruptions), length.out = 10))
```

However, here I am re-specifying within the `geom_histogram()` function that I want `faithful$eruptions`. I have been unable to find a way to phrase this without re-specifying. Further, if I use the `data =` argument in `geom_histogram()`, and specify just `eruptions` in `min` and `max`, `seq()` still doesn't understand that I mean the `faithful` data set.

I know that `seq` is not part of ggplot2, but I wondered if it might be able to inherit regardless, as it is bound within `geom_histogram()`, which itself inherits from `ggplot()`. Am I just using the wrong syntax, or is this possible?

Comment: I dont know that what you are asking is possible, I would us seq_along instead of min / max btw.,

Comment: @grrgrrbla, it may well not be. I'm just trying to work out what is and isn't. thanks for the seq_along tip  :)

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer your question, but you may shorten your code by writing aes(x=eruptions) and then min(x) and max(x) respectively.

Comment: @maj, I'm afraid I can't get that to work. I've tried a few permutations of `aes(x = eruptions)` in both `ggplot()` and `geom_histogram()`, then replacing  `min/max`. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @DaveRGP, I'm only saying that `ggplot(data = faithful, aes(x=eruptions)) + geom_histogram(breaks = seq(from = min(x), to = max(x), length.out = 5))` has the same effect as your example that uses `faithful$eruptions` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the term you are looking for is not "inheritance", but non standard evaluation (NSE).  `ggplot` offers a couple of places where you can refer to your data items by their column names instead of a full reference (NSE), but those are the `mapping` arguments to the `geom_*` layers only, and even then when you are using `aes`.  These work:

```
ggplot(faithful) + geom_point(aes(eruptions, eruptions))
ggplot(faithful) + geom_point(aes(eruptions, eruptions, size=waiting))
```

The following doesn't work because we are referring to `waiting` outside of `aes` and `mapping` (note first arg to `geom_*` is the `mapping` arg):

```
ggplot(faithful) + geom_point(aes(eruptions, eruptions), size=waiting)
```

But this works:

```
ggplot(faithful) + geom_point(aes(eruptions, eruptions), size=faithful$waiting)
```

though differently since now `size` is being interpreted litterally instead of being normalized as when part of `mapping`.

In your case, since `breaks` is not part of the `aes`/`mapping` spec, you can't use NSE and you are left using the full reference.  Some possible work-arounds:

```
ggplot(data = faithful, aes(eruptions)) + geom_histogram(bins=10)  # not identical
ggplot(data=faithful, aes(eruptions)) + 
  geom_histogram(
    breaks=with(faithful,  # use `with`
      seq(from=max(eruptions), to=min(eruptions), length.out=10)
  ) )
```

And no-NSE, but a little less typing:

```
ggplot(data=faithful, aes(eruptions)) + 
  geom_histogram(
    breaks=do.call(seq, c(as.list(range(faithful$eruptions)), len=10))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the ggplot2 documentation it seems that `+` operator which is really the `+.gg` function allows adding the following objects to a ggplot object:
data.frame, uneval, layer, theme, scale, coord, facet

The `geom` function are functions that create layers which inherit the `data` and `aes` from the ggplot object "above" unless stated otherwise.

However the ggplot object and functions "live" in the Global environment, and thus calling a function such as `seq` which doesn't create a ggplot object from the ones listed above and doesn't inherit the ggplot object's themes (with the `+` operator which apply's to the listed above objects) lives in the global environment which doesn't include an object `eruptions`